# Need to find a response time which takes from 1-3 seconds in Apache logs

Tags: text-processing

I need to find the API response time from an Apache log file. It's like a response time which is takes between 1 to 2 secound or 2 to 3 second. `$6` is response time and values comes in microseconds.

I am trying with following command but the output is always the same:

```
grep 17/Sep/2016:10 /access.log| awk '{print ($6 > 1000000 && 2000000 > $6)}' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

This question would be clearer if some lines of `access.log` were added as a sample. Anyway, the awk command prints a line regardless of the value of `$6`, so when you count the lines with `wc -l` you get an outcome that is determined by grep alone.

If you want to count the lines where is `$6` is between two different values you can write

```
grep 17/Sep/2016:10 /access.log | awk '$6 > 1000000 && 2000000 > $6' | wc -l
```

However, this pipeline is a bit inefficient. It would almost always be preferable to combine it in a single awk command like this:

```
awk '/17\/Sep\/2016:10/ && $6 > 1000000 && 2000000 > $6 {c++} END{print c}' access.log
```

To include the boundaries one can do:

```
grep 18/Sep/2016:11 /access.log | awk ' $6>=1000000 && $6<=2000000' | wc -l
```

or equivalently

```
awk '/18\/Sep\/2016:11/ && $6>=1000000 && $6<=2000000 {c++} END{print c}' access.log
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot , i want to say one thing i used another coommand which is gave same answer.command is here is it write or not #  grep 17/Sep/2016:10 /access.log | awk ' $6>=1000000 && $6<=2000000' | wc -l

Comment: @roshan: Sure that should also work, if you want to include the boundary values

Comment: yes its giving same value i checked many times output is same always.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Perl**

*String conditional to only return lines with match in 1st column (no `grep` required). Use `ne` instead of `eq` to omit matching lines*:

```
~$ perl -lane 'print if $F[0] eq "Mar";'  file
Mar 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000002 7th
```

*Numeric inequalities to return lines with desired values in 6th column:*

```
~$ perl -lane 'print if $F[5] >= 1000000 && $F[5] < 3000000;'  file
Feb 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000001 7th
Mar 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000002 7th
Apr 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000003 7th
May 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 2000001 7th
Jun 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 2000002 7th
```

*Putting conditionals together:*

```
~$ perl -lane 'if (($F[0] ne "Mar") && ($F[5] >= 1000000) && ($F[5] < 3000000)) {print $_};'  file
Feb 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000001 7th
Apr 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000003 7th
May 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 2000001 7th
Jun 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 2000002 7th
```

*Using a line counter for final output:*

```
~$ perl -lane 'BEGIN {$line_cnt}; if (($F[0] ne "Mar") && ($F[5] >= 1000000) && ($F[5] < 3000000)) {++$line_cnt}; END {print $line_cnt};'  file
4
```

---

Sample Input:

```
Jan 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 999999 7th
Feb 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000001 7th
Mar 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000002 7th
Apr 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000003 7th
May 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 2000001 7th
Jun 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 2000002 7th
Jul 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 3000001 7th
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Perl_Programming/Conditionals
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678272/perl-script-to-count-words-lines
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727962/227738

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*String conditional to only return lines with match in 1st column (no `grep` required). The `.words` routine splits on whitespace. Use `ne` instead of `eq` to omit matching lines*:

```
~$ raku -ne '.put if .words[0] eq "Mar";'  file
Mar 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000002 7th
```

*Chained numeric inequalities to return lines with desired values in 6th column:*

```
~$ raku -ne '.put if 1000000 <= .words[5] < 3000000;'  file
Feb 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000001 7th
Mar 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000002 7th
Apr 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000003 7th
May 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 2000001 7th
Jun 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 2000002 7th
```

*Putting conditionals together:*

```
~$ raku -ne '.put if .words[0] ne "Mar"  &&  1000000 <= .words[5] < 3000000;'   file
Feb 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000001 7th
Apr 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000003 7th
May 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 2000001 7th
Jun 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 2000002 7th
```

*Using a line counter for final output:*

```
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my $line_cnt; ++$line_cnt if .words[0] ne "Mar"  &&  1000000 <= .words[5] < 3000000; END put $line_cnt;'   file
4
```

---

Sample Input:

```
Jan 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 999999 7th
Feb 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000001 7th
Mar 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000002 7th
Apr 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 1000003 7th
May 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 2000001 7th
Jun 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 2000002 7th
Jul 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 3000001 7th
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Tight_AND_precedence
https://docs.raku.org/language/phasers
https://raku.org